# Environment Variable cannot be found in docker container

Tags: python-3.x, docker, environment-variables, ubuntu-server

I'm trying to setup a docker container on a Ubuntu server for a discord bot.

I have run the following on the Ubuntu server:

```
export DISCORD_TOKEN = "*****"

sudo docker run --env DISCORD_TOKEN  me/my-docker-repo
```

In the bot code I have:

```
import os
TOKEN = os.environ['DISCORD_TOKEN']
```

when the container is ran it gives the python error "KeyError: 'DISCORD_TOKEN'"

Comment: Try adding docker to the current user's user group. Thereafter, login into a new bash session, set the environment variable: `DISCORD_TOKEN` again and run the `docker run` command without sudo. That should fix your problem.

Comment: try an .env file

Comment: This works Divij Sehgal. It does Warn that the config file cannot be loaded but the container runs now. Thanks!

Comment: @KGB33 I'll add that as an answer so that you can mark this as closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Answer to the original question(From my comment above):**

Try adding docker to the current user's user group. Thereafter, login into a new bash session, set the environment variable: DISCORD_TOKEN(and any other variables) again and run the command without `sudo` as follows:

```
sudo docker run --env DISCORD_TOKEN  me/my-docker-repo
```

That should fix your problem.

**Reason**

This happens because when you start a container with the `sudo` prefix, it looks not in the current user, but in the root user's environment variable definitions. So without the `sudo` prefix, it looks in the current user's environment variable definitions.

---

The other problem regarding load failure of `config file`, this might help:
[Docker can’t load config file, but container works fine](https://forums.docker.com/t/docker-cant-load-config-file-but-container-works-fine/26777)

Answer (score 1):

`sudo` by default resets the shell environment variables to a minimum set of "known safe" variables.  If you use the `sudo -E` option it will preserve environment variables

```
sudo -E docker run --env DISCORD_TOKEN  me/my-docker-repo
```

You can also pass the container-side environment variables directly on the command line, without setting it as such in the parent shell

```
sudo docker run --env DISCORD_TOKEN="*****" me/my-docker-repo
```